# how can I render the contents of a javascript map object as a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, html-lists

I needed to use a map instead of a JavaScript object because I needed to use "names" as a way to look for data. I know I could have set a name values in each object and looked through each objects name value, but this seemed easier at first. The map is a react state hook.

code:

```
const [champs, setChamps] = useState(new Map())

<ul>
  {[...champs.keys()].map( k => (
     <li key={k}>champs.get(k)</li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, though a Map in state is pretty unusual, since they need to be cloned. What problems are you running into?

Comment: I don't think the spread is necessary if you only want the keys, and you're missing a `]`. If you want both keys and values, use `[...champs]` without the `keys()` call. That's probably faster and more semantic than calling `.get` over and over.

Comment: my bad, I edited the code to fix my missing ].

Comment: The problem is that I am rendering the litteral "champs.get(k)". Can you show me an example of what you mean @ggorlen?

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that too. Add braces: `{champs.get(k)}`.

Comment: got things to finally work, thank you very much @ggorlen!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you're missing is the `{}` around your `champs.get(k)`.

I may be wrong though.

Comment: yes I managed to fix my issue by wrapping champs.get(k), then using the .to get my specific values